# Maximum Vgs for MOSFETs with kelvin source

Tags: mosfet, gate-driving, maximum-ratings

There are some MOSFET packages with an additional kelvin source pin that provides a low inductance driver source connection:

[image]

<sub>Source: [CREE C3M0060065J](https://www.wolfspeed.com/downloads/dl/file/id/1629/product/465/c3m0060065j.pdf)</sub>

Datasheets also specify a maximum \$V_{GS}\$, for example:

[image]

<sub>Source: [CREE C3M0060065J](https://www.wolfspeed.com/downloads/dl/file/id/1629/product/465/c3m0060065j.pdf)</sub>

Now the question is, does \$V_{GS}\$ mean the voltage between Gate and Power Source or Gate and Driver Source? The difference is quite significant when a current in a Half-Bridge is switched relatively quickly. When simulating with a SPICE Model of the linked CREE MOSFET the comparison looks like this:

[image]

When the other MOSFET of the Half-Bridge is switched off at about \$29.3 \mu \mathrm{s}\$, there is a small dip in the green Gate-Driver Source voltage and a more significant oscillation in the blue Gate-Power Source voltage. Measurements on a MOSFET produce similar results.

I would assume, that a voltage across the additional Power Source inductance is rather meaningless for the health of the die and that \$V_{GS}\$ is meant to be the voltage of Gate to Driver Source. Is this correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is neither.

The important figure is the voltage between gate and body because that is where the dielectric is.

The voltage on package pins will be different due to the lead inductance but this voltage will not appear on the body itself.

I would argue that the kelvin source pin is closer to the body potential because it sees less L dI/dt.

To bring this into context with the Cree datasheet: The actual gate-body safe voltages seem to be -4 / +15 V. Taking into account the typical switching voltage spikes measured on the device pins, Cree demands to keep spikes smaller than -8 / +19 V.

For SiC MOSFET the gate capacitance is actually pretty low and gate current during these spikes can affect the gate voltage a lot in contrast to what was written here before. I understand their datasheet in terms of the voltage measured between gate and Kelvin source.

Answer (score 3):

Driver source and power source are internally connected, so there is not much difference in terms of voltage.

The difference is how the pins are attached to the silicon, usually using bonded gold wires.

The Driver source perhaps only has one and power source several to accommodate for current, so as long as you don't pull too much current on the driver source, which is only meant for measurement, there won't be voltage differences.

The reason of it, is that at high current, you will have voltage drop at several places internally in the component, thus for a very accurate voltage reading, at the die, they place an additional pin that has no current, thus no voltage drop due to impedance, method which is called the Kelvin method (for some reason).

Thus to answer your question, Vgs would rather be the voltage to the Driver source, given no significant current is flowing through that pin, as one will assume the value given are for the actual silicon die and does not consider the package, otherwise you would have a Vgs / Ids graph on the datasheet.